# C++ : Pass Dynamic Functions and Store Functions?

Tags: c++, function

I have two questions regarding functions in C++: can you dynamically declare a function when passing it as a reference, and is it possible to store functions to use later?

**Passing Dynamic Function?**

My question may not be worded perfectly clear, but what I mean is in Java you quite often see code that looks like:

```
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener( ) 
{
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
        System.out.println( "..." );
    }
} );
```

or JavaScript:

```
$( ".class" ).each( function( )
{
    alert( "..." );
} );
```

While in C++ you are limited to:

```
void print( )
{
    std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
}

void func( void ( &f )( ) )
{
    f( );
}

// ...

func( print );
```

and can not do something like

```
void func( void ( &f )( ) )
{
    f( );
}

// ...

func( void f( ){ ... } );
```

Is this just a limitation to C++?

**Storing Functions?**

Is it at all possible to store similar functions into a container to be called later? An example of the idea (which does not work) is:

```
std::vector< void( ) > storage;

void callMeLater( void ( &f )( ) )
{
    storage.push_back( f );
}

void popFunction( )
{
    void f( ) = storage.pop_back( );
    f( );
}
```

These ideas both came to me when working on an Event system, to see if my Timer object could also handle delayed functions as well as event calls. As I have never seen these used in any C++ code, I doubt they are possible but would love to be shown otherwise!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current standard, it has become very easy:

```
#include <functional>

void foo (std::function<float(float,float)> bar) {
    std::cout << bar (0.5, 0.75);

    std::function<float(float,float)> frob = bar;
}
```

Within the angle brackets you declare the output (a single float in this case) and input (two floats).

You could then call it like this:

```
float perlin_noise_function (float x, float z) { ... }

class PerlinNoiseFunctor : public std::binary_function<float(float,float)>
{...};

int main () {
    // pass function pointer
    foo (perlin_noise);

    // pass functor
    PerlinNoiseFunctor pnf;
    foo (pnf);

    // pass lambda function
    foo ([] (float x, float z) { ... });
}
```

You could also replace `foo` like this:

```
template <typename F>
void foo (F f) ;
```